# When to use block patterns over nested blocks?

Tags: block-editor

Struggling to understand the differences between the recently introduced block patterns and a custom block with nested blocks (inner blocks) [paired with a template](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/#template). To me they seem to achieve the same thing.

When should one opt to use block patterns over nested blocks and vice versa?

Comment: Block patterns are just predefined groups of blocks so that you can insert multiple blocks at a time. Patterns can contain nested blocks. It's like on TV where someone says _"here's something I made earlier"_ in a handy menu. Anything you can do with a block pattern is something you can do with existing blocks if you add them in the right way, they don't add new functionality, they just save time

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but you could potentially do that with nested blocks paired with a template aswell (and if you want to go further, add default values for those blocks). And since you can lock the order etc it feels like you can get even more granular with nested blocks aswell. Therefor I wonder why I should opt for patterns over that.

Comment: However if you've created something that is used in multiple locations and the intent is to look the same everytime it's used, then the block pattern might make more sense to me.

Comment: If you're using custom blocks to do things that can be achieved by just combining the blocks that come with WP Core, then that is the mistake. For example, adding a left/right media block when you can just use a column block with an image in one column and text in the other